# ESC Fargate working fine with HTTP but on HTTPS it recreate tasks each 3 minutes

Tags: aws-fargate

I have a task definition with two containers :

- backend (Spring boot) : export port 8080
- Frontend (react + nginx) : export port 80

and Application load balancer (ALB)

My application works fine with this configuration (HTTP), but when I integrate HTTPS, Fargate shutdown/recreate task every 3 minutes.

The changes I added to integrate https :

- export port 80 and 443 on frontend
- add a listner to ALB listners (HTTPS : 443)
- add inbound rule to security group of ALB (HTTPS : 443)
- add certificat ACM

NB : The new deployment (HTTPS) works from a browser, on the other hand the shutdown/recreate of the tasks which I have problem.

I have this error:

> Task failed ELB health checks in (target-group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-3:XXXXX:targetgroup/GLOBAL_TARGET/XXXXXXXXXX)

I'm using this nginx config for https :

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.html;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    client_max_body_size 500M ;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/api/;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your target group health check settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed this code from my nginx file and with other configs on load balancer

```
if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https' ) {
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The health check failing for you Fargate service.

try this,

While creating ALB, Listen to the load balancer to port 443, and for the target group. listen to port 80.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Using Target Group at port 80 should work as Ahishek said. Port: 80 | Protocol: HTTP